# Twig cache won't disable

Tags: caching

I've set up my development setup and it works great but for some reason I can't get the twig cache to disable. I tried everything, but I have to run drush cr every time I change anything in twig templates, and it's driving me insane.

settings.php:

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
  include __DIR__ . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

settings.local.php AND setting.php:

```
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;

$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';

$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

services.yml AND development.services.yml

```
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

I am running Drupal 8.4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Drupal 8.4 you have to set the null cache backend for an additional cache bin, so now there are three:

*settings.local.php:*

```
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['page'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

This is because the cached pages for anonymous users moved to a separate cache bin, see the change record *[The internal page cache now has a dedicated cache bin](https://www.drupal.org/node/2896679)*.

Comment: If you have an error like _You have requested a non-existent service "cache.backend.null"_, see also : [cache.backend.null is defined in development.services.yml](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/303820/drupal9-dev-mode-local-settings-non-existing-cache-backend-null)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Mix](https://www.drupal.org/project/mix) module to **disable drupal caches** during development by just toggling an "Enable development mode" checkbox, which will saving us a lot of time in settings*.php and services*.yml files.

Comment: Version tags should be used for questions that apply to a version only, not to merely say what version a site is using. Please stop adding tags.